# Angular - ng.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system

Tags: angular

In my Angular-12 Application, I tried to generate service using:

> ng g s auth/services/login

but I got this error:

```
ng : File C:\Users\akweey\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more 
information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ ng g s auth/services/login
+ ~~
+ CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

When I checked the path: C:\Users\akweey\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1,

I only found ng but no ng.ps1

How do I get this resolved?

Thanks

Answer (score 130, accepted):

This issue occurs due to undefined Execution policy.

Try this command in Powershell:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Comment: Keep in mind, there are security implications when enabling an Unrestricted ExecutionPolicy for scripts.

Comment: try run in terminal of vs code good luck

Answer (score 34):

Just delete this file.
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1

Comment: This is the best answer here. The other solutions have the user creating security vulnerabilities on their system.

Comment: There is no such file.

Comment: worked for me!!

Answer (score 5):

execute this on powershell,

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

for next, "Do you want to change the execution policy?" give "yes to all"

```
A
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to the path of your npm install

```
 C:\Users\{user_name}\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

and delete **ng.ps1** file from location and recomplie the programme.

Answer (score 1):

open the PowerShell with administrative rights. and run those commands:

1. set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
2. Get-ExecutionPolicy
3. Get-ExecutionPolicy -list

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to the current user having an undefined ExecutionPolicy.

In PowerShell as Administrator, you could try the following:

`Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`

Run above command on terminal. I was facing this issue on my intellij after upgrading the node and angular version.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I have installed the ng (angular in globally ) and trying to access in E:\ drive got above error, I executed the above given command, then now working fine for me.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue while running in **Windows Powershell**. But same command **works in traditional command prompt**. Might help for someone.

I did no change in windows policy. Below is default setting in my system.

PS C:\Users\krishna> Get-ExecutionPolicy -list

```
        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser       Undefined
 LocalMachine      Restricted
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're in *Windows*, easy solution is adding to "ng" the correct file extension:

***ng*** g s auth/services/login (***ERROR!***)

***ng.cmd*** g s auth/services/login (***OK!***)

Answer (score -1):

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Open PowerShell Termial and try to run the above command.

This worked for me.

(You might need to reopen the terminal)